# QRegularExpression: cannot make part of match optional

Tags: regex, qt

Given the following string:

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF8h/ls5JiSNQB5gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== "this is a tooltip"

that should represent a data url of an image, I should extract all the parts of it so I made a RegEx for it:

str = "`(data:(\w+)/(\w+);base64,)(.*)(\"([\w*|\s*]*)\")`"

It works as with the following code:

```
QRegularExpressionMatch match = regex.match(str);
for(int i = 0; i <= match.lastCapturedIndex(); ++i )
    ui->outputBrowser->append(QString::number(i) + ": " + match.captured(i));
```

I can see:

```
0: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF8h/ls5JiSNQB5gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== "this is a tooltip"
1: data:image/png;base64,
2: image
3: png
4: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF8h/ls5JiSNQB5gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== 
5: "this is a tooltip"
6: this is a tooltip
```

But if I add a `?` to the end of the RegEx, it doesn't work.
The *`"this is a tooltip"`* - **that is optional** - goes to the data part and not in a standalone part.

str = "`(data:(\w+)/(\w+);base64,)(.*)(\"([\w*|\s*]*)\")?`"

output:

```
0: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF8h/ls5JiSNQB5gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== "this is a tooltip"
1: image/png;base64,
2: image
3: png
4: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF8h/ls5JiSNQB5gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== "this is a tooltip"
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
(data:(\w+)/(\w+);base64,)([^"]*)(\"([\w\s]*)\")?
                           ^^^^^                ^
```

The `.*` is too greedy and matches every character but a newline, 0 or more occurrences. In order to be able to make the last group optional, you need to restrict this subpattern. You can do it with `[^"]*` negated character class.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sI9cO7/1)

Also note that `[\w*|\s*]` is matching a single character that is alphanumeric or underscore (`\w`), a whitespace (`\s`), `|` or `*`. Inside a character class, `|` and `*` are literal pipe and asterisk symbols.